# Imagemagick convert command in php script not working

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using php imagemagick and i want to run convert command in php script but it don't work.

My code is here-

```
<?php
    exec( "/usr/bin/convert new2.png output.jpg");
 ?>
```

new2.png is in the same directory.

Comment: Hi Kusum Gupta - could you [edit] your question to explain more clearly what is not working. For example, do you get an error? Or does something else happen you weren't expecting?

Comment: @Vince, trying to convert image format (**png to jpg**) through php program execution method ` exec() ` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php] and open image in browser. Basically i have a file new.php which contain block of code-- `<?php exec("/usr/bin/convert new2.png output.jpg"); ?>` When i execute this file in my local server i.e. localhost/new.php i get no output.   i want to display this converted image  in browser with jpg format.

Answer (score -1):

It is a while since I tried this:

1/ php page with you php code called for instance image.php

2/ On another html page use

```
<img src="image.php">
```

I assume your image would display if you refreshed your page. When the page loads the image is created but it is not there for the image tag to display.